# Does almost linux-like OS support ifconfig command with same usage?

Tags: linux, ifconfig

I want to make `ifconfig` parser and runner with Python

Beginning of this question, I want to use simple API like this.

```
import ifconfig

ifconfig.interfaces['eth0'].ip = '192.168.0.123' # run subprocess internally
```

But I don't know all linux-like OS.

So I choose using `ifconfig` command. But I also don't know all linux-like OS support `ifconfig` command.

Can I know what OS do not support `ifconfig` basically and how to make it work? And they support same usage?

Comment: What do you mean with linux-like? Unix like?

Comment: If you mean other unix-variants: there are a lot of differences between implementations, both in command-syntax and in output-format. (the same goes for route, arp, mount, ...) So initially you should stick to linux and make it possible to add parsers for different dialects. (OSX is BSD-based, so that might be a good 2nd candidate)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are better off using `ip` command instead. `ip` is more generic and there are some distributions which don't include `ifconfig` in their default configuration. For example `ArchLinux` includes `ifconfig` only because it might break some old scripts. Same for CentOS7 and RHEL7. It seems like `ifconfig` will be outdated in a few years.

Take a look at [wikipedia page for ifconfig](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ifconfig) it has good summery of the current use of `ifconfig` among different systems.

So almost all Linux distributions include `ifconfig`. But at least some straight forward distributions only for backward compatibility. `ifconfig` support for other Unix like OS is quite good.